# Get Join To Recognize Only Registered Groups?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I am trying to select the groups that a user have signed up to which is specified in the members table 
and display updates on one page of all groups a user is a member of, but every time it keeps displaying updates from every group that has been created, even if they are not a member. So how can I make it that only groups that a user is joined to those updates will display?

Here's my query so far:

```
    $select_posts_from_groups_query = $db->query("SELECT spud_groups_posts.post_body,spud_groups_posts.group_url,spud_groups_members.member_name
         FROM spud_groups_posts LEFT JOIN spud_groups_members ON spud_groups_posts.post_body = spud_groups_members.member_name");


        while($select_posts_from_groups_array = $db->fetch_array($select_posts_from_groups_query)) {

            $group_url_id = $select_posts_from_groups_array['group_url'];
            $post_body = $select_posts_from_groups_array['post_body'];

            $select_group_data_from_posts_query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM spud_groups WHERE gid='$group_url_id'");
            $select_group_data_from_posts_array = $db->fetch_array($select_group_data_from_posts_query);
            $group_name_data = $select_group_data_from_posts_array['group_name'];


                #$group_name_data = false;
            echo "<div class='mx'> 
        <p> <h2> $group_name_data </h2></p>
        $post_body</div>
<br>
        ";
    }
```

Never done SQL joins before so that's why.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: I extended the PHP so you can all get a more of an idea hope this helps ;)

Comment: I can only refer you again to comments made previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a good practice would be to use aliases so that your code will look much better

```
SELECT 
    gr.post_body,
    gr.group_url,
    mem.member_name
FROM 
    spud_groups_posts gr
    LEFT JOIN spud_groups_members mem ON 
        gr.post_body = mem.member_name
```

This query will give you all results from table `spud_groups_posts` and matching results from `spud_groups_members`.

You should replace LEFT JOIN with JOIN or INNER JOIN (same results).

---

As you've mentioned in a comment your ResultSet is empty - that means you have no matching values in columns `post_body` from table `spud_groups_posts` with `member_name` from 
`spud_groups_members`

Comment: thanks loads so far :) the only issue I need to solve now is to only loop updates from groups that the user is joined to so basically if there assigned a table for a certain group_url in the members table

Comment: Could you please show us your tables by editing your question and make it a bit more clear about what you would like to do, as I see no UPDATE statement in your code.

Comment: when I say updates I am referring to posts/records in a database but I call them updates I should explain better ;) if you still need the tables let me know

Comment: Yes please, give us your tables with columns and references and rephrase what is the problem you are facing now.

Comment: thanks I wrote a query out which worked :D
thanks for guiding me in the right direction

Comment: Good to hear, you could also edit your post with appropriate query that works and a question to it, just for the future searches :)

Answer (score 0):

In your select you're using a LEFT JOIN.
Therefore alle the groups are selected.

You have to use an INNER JOIN instead.

Comment: ok i try that this is the first time ive used these joins statements so I am a complete noob at them so I do apologize if I do sound dumb

Comment: replacing join with innser gives me a blank page so it's not looping nothing

Comment: is there any other way to do this method without joins

Comment: You are joining field POST_BODY with MEMBER_NAME. A join must be set between fields with the same content. In which field/table are the groups stored where a user belongs to ?

Comment: Im now using the query that nobodynoone wrote below all I am trying to do now is try to make it equal to the groups that the logged in user is a member off.

Comment: Can you provide all tables (and their columns). The known tables/columns of the original question are not enough for a correct join.

Comment: I find a solution :D 
This query works and thanks for trying to help I accept both of your answers ;)
i can't upvote which is stupid.. or accept both answers...